# Should HTTP server return 200 when PUT is a no-op?

Tags: rest, http

I've reread the HTTP spec.

It states that PUT should be treated as a request to *modify* the existing resource if the resource has already been created.

It states that PUT should return either 200 or 204 when it succeeds, but did not create the resource.

It states that PUT should be idempotent and have no unwanted *side effects* when it is invoked multiple times with the same identical request.

What it does not seem to state is that
-PUT should return success when it is an idempotent scenario with no side effects, and only success, (and not e.g. 409 conflict in response to a server detected no-op PUT request where the server wants to disallow no-ops).

My question is, what is the best thing to do?
Either:

1. did I miss anything? Either in HTTP spec, or other well-known REST guidelines, what didn't I see?

or

2. assuming you know of nothing I missed, what is your opinion on whether 200 should be HTTP's recommended behavior? Why? Can you think of any good reason not to return 200/204 for a no-op?

Comment: If a no-op (by which I assume you mean a PUT to an existing resource that doesn't actually change its value) is 'success' in your system it should return 200. I don't see anything in your quotations that says otherwise.

Comment: All the other 2xx codes make absolutely no sense in your scenario, so 200 or 204 seems ok

Comment: Basically yeah it doesn't change the value and I don't see why that wouldn't be considered a success.. unless someone has a good argument? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should return 200 or 204.

First of all, PUT is not treated as a request to modify the existing resource. You're probably reading [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6), which is obsoleted by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) on this. PUT is always a request to **replace** the resource at the given URI, but this wasn't very clear on RFC 2616. In case it already exists, the paylod SHOULD be a modified version of the same resource, but the operation still is a complete replacement, not a modification.

In that sense, there's no such thing as `no-op` PUT, you're always replacing what is identified by that URI, even if by the exact same thing. Whether changes occurred from the point of view of the client is irrelevant. For the server, what matters is that the whole thing was replaced.

As a general rule, the semantics of the GET, PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods should be easily generalized for everything, and if you're adding to their semantics something already available through something else, you're probably doing something wrong. To return an error on a no-op request because no changes would occur to the resource can be achieved with the precondition headers if that's what the client wants, so it doesn't make sense to make that part of the PUT semantics.

Comment: Because of the exact words of the RFC spec "If the target
   resource does have a current representation and that representation
   is successfully _modified_" I think it's still not 100% clear, but I agree, I want it to have the same interpretation you give it, and your argument about precondition headers also makes perfect sense.